# How to override material-ui component class

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I want to change width of SnackbarContent, and trying to overrride root css api. How can I do it?

```js
<SnackbarContent
    className={classNames(classes[variant], classes.badge)}
    classes={{
          root: {
            flexGrow: 1
          }
        }}
    //or
    classes={{root: 'flexGrow: 1'}}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that would be

```js
<SnackbarContent
  classes={{
    root: {
      flexGrow: 1
    }
  }}
/>
```